# Kernels property: integral of kernel product $\propto k(x,y)$

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick, integral, rbf-kernel

Let $k$ be a kernel function (symmetric and semi-positive definite function).

Does the following relationship hold:

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}k(x,u)k(y,u) du \propto k(x,y)$ ?

Or for what type of kernels does it hold?

I know that in the case of RBF Gaussian kernel it holds (see [here](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf): page 102 pdf; page 84 print; it relates to Gaussian processes; a positive answer would help me generalize this RBF property to any kernel function).